# RelativeLayout with a negative offset does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a 3 x 3 grid of map tiles (images) on an android view. These images are load dynamically and then i want to move the Relative layout by a set amount (this will always be negative). I can do this successfully in HTML but when i try it on a RelativeLayout in Android it does not work.

I've tried using the following but it does not work:

```
View view = this.findViewById(R.id.mapContrainer);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
head_params.setMargins(leftOffset, topOffset, 0, 0);
view.setLayoutParams(head_params);
```

Here's my of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />   

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="current location"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_gravity="center"     
     />



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locationIcon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"            
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map_person"

        />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapContrainer"
    android:layout_width="768dp"
    android:layout_height="768dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-400dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-400dp"          
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapImage1"           
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapImage2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapImage1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mapImage1"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapImage1"           
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapImage4"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapImage1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapImage5"        
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapImage4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mapImage1"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapImage4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapImage7"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapImage9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_light" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapImage4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapImage8"
    />
</RelativeLayout>   
</RelativeLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    layout="@layout/menu_layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try putting requestLayout() after setting the layout param?

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I've been wondering if I needed to do something like this.